# Upstart job not running at boot

Tags: upstart

Hi all I have been trying to figure out my problem for some time and think it is now time to ask someone who know more than me. Hopefully this is only a simple solution for someone in the know

Basically I have 2 upstart scripts that I created but only 1 will run at boot and the other will not although both run fine when called manually

Here is the one that works

```
# status led daemon
#

description "Status led daemon; Used for controlling the server status led"
author "None"

start on (started dbus and started mountall)
stop on (xbmc-do-stop or runlevel [!2345])

exec led.sh
respawn
```

and here is the one that does not

```
# irexec daemon
#

description "irexec daemon"
author "None"

start on (started dbus and started mountall)
stop on (xbmc-do-stop or runlevel [!2345])

exec irexec /home/pi/.lircrc
respawn
```

as you can see they are very similar and I cannot find out why one will work but the other will not

Comment: So the latter is not running at all, or just failing silently? what does `dmesg|grep init:` tell you?

Comment: It is failing to start and `dmesg` shows nothing. If I start it manually after boot by using `sudo service irexec start` then it will run fine and respawn when it gets killed.

Comment: You could verify that the upstart job really doesn't have been executed adding a `script ... end script` block like that: http://pastebin.com/RMF7HE62 (sorry, I'm not be abble to add a code block here)